# How Do I Change The Azure App Service To Display A Different Timezone?

Tags: azure

I have deployed my App Service to Canada Central and the webapp is using the F1 Free tier using Linux.

When I go to "Diagnose and solve problems" the time range is in UTC instead of EST.

How do I change the Timezone of the Azure web console to display EST so that I can more easily work out what went wrong and when?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

App services default to UTC.  You can change that by setting the "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE" app setting to any valid Windows timezone (under "Configuration" tab / "Application Settings"). So in your case "Eastern Standard Time".

EDIT:

Actually, for Linux (which I rarely use), Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-configuration-and-management) say you should use the "IANA TZ database timezone" value, such as "America/New_York"

This timezone setting is specific to this app service and is independent of the timezone set in your MS account, which is what is used generally in the portal.

Comment: Is that going to change what is shown in the portal as well as the timezone in the container?

Comment: It changes the timezone on the underlying app service VM.  So if you mean how the specific server's logs display in the portal, then yes.  It should show the service's time.  General times in the portal will be whatever timezone setting you have for your MS account. Metrics being sent to general services like Azure Monitor may be normalized to UTC or your portal timezone (not sure).

Comment: My MS account DID say UTC for some reason, which is very strange since my connected Office 365 account doesn't say that. Can you update the answer to include this info too so I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm just getting tired, but I'm not clear on what "info" you are asking me to add to the answer.

Comment: Just the bit about the MS Account

Comment: under Linux appservices use `TZ` as the key